# Visual Studio not auto correcting Python code

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, indentation

When trying to write code in Visual Studio, doing an if else statement results in an error as Visual Studio isn't removing the indentation before the else that's inserted after moving to a new line.

I have my indentation mode set to "smart" but have tried "block" as well which seems to do the same thing as "none". I've read that "block" should insert as many spaces or tabs as the previous line but this isn't the case for me.

In an IDE like Spyder, once I end a line with a colon ':', the appropriate indentation is either added or removed depending on the circumstance.